# How to get highest count of associated model (Rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many

A User has_many Solutions

How do I order Users by those with the most Solutions?

I'm trying to find the top ten users but I'm not sure how the most tidy or efficient way to do this?

Does anyone have an example that isn't too computationally expensive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really want a fast way of doing it, put a `counter_cache` on a users' solutions (have a `solutions_count` column in your `User`) and order by that column. You don't need to manage that counter, because rails does it for you. You can read more about `counter_cache` in the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Answer (score 26):

```
User
  .joins(:solutions)
  .select("users.*, count(solutions.id) as scount")
  .group("users.id")
  .order("scount DESC")
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the following models

```
class User
  has_many :solutions
end

class Solution
 belongs_to :user
end
```

Then the best way is to counter_cache the solutions_count and order by it. [more on counter_cache](http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column)

The query will then be

```
User.order("users.solutions_count DESC").limit(10)
```

Don't forget to index the solutions_count column.