# rails 3.1 How to retrieve in a query those elements with the maximum number of relationships in a many to many?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rails-3.1

I have tried different combinations but it seems that I cannot work this out.

I want to retrieve, from an Event model, those events which have the biggest number of users.

For example, I retrieve users of an event like this

```
@users = Event.find(x).users
```

They can be counted using this

```
Event.find(x).users.count
```

So, How should be done to order the list by the number of users each event has. And then retrieve the 8 first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same issue was resolved in: [How to get highest count of associated model (Rails)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9739451/how-to-get-highest-count-of-associated-model-rails/9739625#9739625)

```
Event.order("events.users_count DESC")
```

Comment: You are right! I did search it but could not find anything. Thanks!