# scope_method to return user_id with most reviews

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a schema that has reviews for my website.

```
  create_table "reviews", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "stars"
    t.string "title"
    t.string "content"
    t.integer "turtle_id"
    t.integer "user_id"
  end
```

I am trying to write a scope_method that returns the `user_id` with the most reviews. I understand I have to write a sql query that counts up multiple instances of `user_id` and then returns that `user_id`. But I am lost at doing so.

This is what I have so far.

```
 scope :most_reviews, -> { 
    where("select count(*) c from reviews group by user_id order by c desc limit 1")
  }
```

I then call it from my controller as so:

```
  def index
    @most_reviewed = Review.most_reviews
    puts @most_reviewed
  end
```

How can i properly write this scope_method to return the `user_id` in reviews with the most reviews?(Otherwise occurrences)? Also this needs to be a scope_method.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9739451/how-to-get-highest-count-of-associated-model-rails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

**Controller:**

```
  def index
    @most_reviewed = Review.most_reviews.first
    puts @most_reviewed
  end
```

**Scope:**

```
  scope :most_reviews, -> { select("users.id, COUNT(reviews.user_id) AS reviews_count")
      .joins(:reviews)
      .group(:id)
      .order(reviews_count: :desc)
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

If your end goal is actually the user you're starting on the wrong end.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :reviews

  def self.most_reviews
    select('users.*', 'COUNT(reviews.*) AS reviews_count')
      .joins(:reviews)
      .group(:id)
      .order(reviews_count: :desc)
  end
end
```

[`scope`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scope) is just syntactic sugar to define one-liner class methods. There is nothing actually special about the methods it declares and using it for cases where the code does not fit in a one-liner just hurts readability.

You can also setup a [counter cache](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to-counter-cache) which will let you simplify this down to:

```
class Review < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, counter_cache: true
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :reviews
  scope :most_reviews, ->{ order(reviews_count: :desc) }
end
```

Which is something that actually fits in a scope one-liner.